# how to set User sate in an Async method of silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

how to set User sate in an Async method of silverlight.

Comment: Please provide more details. What are you trying to do? Maybe some code of it. What problem do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the Answer,

Second parameter in Async call is an UserState,
And we can read that in AsyncCompleted method.